# being $\mathbf{w}$ a vector, how do I calculate the derivative of $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, products

Let's say that I have a vector $\mathbf{w}$.

How can I calculate the derivative in the following expression?

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{w}}\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}$

**Update**: found [these useful definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Derivatives_with_vectors)

Comment: Start with a simple example and build from there. The pattern should be clear.

Comment: What's the meaning of $\dfrac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}$?

Comment: Traditionally, it means "a vector whose elements are the derivative of what follows with respect to each coordinate." For instance, if $\mathbf{w} = (x,\ y)$, then $\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}} \left( x^2+y^2\right) = (2x,\ 2y)$.

Comment: @egreg, I am pretty sure this is common notation in optimization, various computer-related fields. Meant o be a directional derivative, so here it would be $w \cdot \nabla f,$ with $f(w) = w \cdot w$ this time.

Comment: @egreg: I am not sure how to express the derivative with regards to a vector $\mathrm{w}$. Maybe it's a shorthand for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}w_1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}w_2}\ldots$, but I am not even sure if this is what is meant with "derivative with regards to a vector"

Comment: @Arkamis: I am surprised to see that the derivative you wrote is not a scalar. Does this mean that the solution is $2\mathbf{w}$ ?

Comment: Yes, in essence. Which makes sense. Because $w^Tw$ is the closest thing you can get to $x^2$ in a vector sense, and hence you would expect the derivative to look something like $2x$, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to see it in component form.

Let $\hat{x_i}$ be the unit vector in the $i$-th direction, then we can express a vector as

$$\mathbf{w}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i \hat{x_i} \tag{1}$$

And

$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}^T_i \frac{d}{dw_i} \tag{2}$$

So

$$\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{w}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 \tag{3}$$

$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{w})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}2w_i\hat{x}^T_i =2\mathbf{w}^T\tag{4}$$

EDIT: I made a minor correction ($\hat{x}_i$ to $\hat{x}^T_i$)in (2) and (4) based on rych's suggestion. Now the final results is $2\mathbf{w}^T$

Comment: should be $2w^T$, no?

Comment: I think that you are right!

Comment: @rych Where is the final transpose coming from?

Comment: @alonsos. I made a minor change in my answer. Please take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) let us calculate the h-linear term,
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
(w+h)^T(w+h)-w^Tw&=(w^T+h^T)(w+h)-w^Tw\approx\\
&\approx h^Tw+w^Th= (h^Tw)^T+w^Th=2w^Th
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$
Hence the derivative is: $2w^T$.
Rather than $2w$. Indeed the gradient is not really a column- but a row-vector (or covector, or dual vector).